# Overlay MapView with hole

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I would to add an overlay on mapView with a hole.

So, I would add a black transparent overlay on my map and on a specific position I would to have this hole through which I can see the map without black overlay.

In this hole I have to show my results. Is possible this?

Comment: would be good if you can add any image for better requirement understanding.

Comment: yes - I've added an overlay to a map for drawing on to circle pins etc. I'm overlay was just a clear UIView

Answer (score 0):

(1)If the overlay could be a simple imageview. Just prepare a png file with full transparent hole and black transparent background.

(2)If you need a dynamic view which might be different at run time, I think the best approach is to prepare a similar image from (1), then apply it as layer mask.

Here is a tuto:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6V_PbCKEO8